# $\mathrm{Tor}_1^R(R/I,R/J)=(I\cap J)/(IJ)$

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, derived-functors

I am proving that $\mathrm{Tor}_1^R(R/I,R/J)=(I\cap J)/(IJ)$. For that, I consider the exact sequence
$0\rightarrow I \rightarrow R\rightarrow R/I\rightarrow 0$, and then I have an long exact sequence

$\begin{align}\DeclareMathOperator{\Tor}{Tor}
\dots\rightarrow0=\Tor^R_1(R,R/J)\rightarrow\Tor^R_1(R/I,R/J)\rightarrow I\otimes_R R/J \rightarrow R/J\rightarrow R/I\otimes_R R/J \rightarrow 0
\end{align}$

By that, to conclude I only need to prove that the map
$
\Tor^R_1(R/I,R/J)\rightarrow I\otimes_R R/J $ is surjective, because in that case by the exactness of the sequence I have the result.

¿Is that map necessary surjective?

Comment: The map you mention is *injective*, not surjective.

Comment: But in that case, how can I conclude that $\mathrm{Tor}_1^R(R/I,R/J)=(I\cap J)/(IJ)$ by computing the kernel of $I/IJ \rightarrow R/J$? I found this is a typical way to prove the main result on several pages. Thank you

Comment: You have to show the kernel of $I\otimes_RR/J\longrightarrow R/I\otimes_RR/J$ is isomorphic to $(I\cap J)/IJ$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition of exact sequence, $\operatorname{Tor}^R_1(R/I,R/J)$ is the kernel of the map $I\otimes_RR/J\to R/J$.

On the other hand, you also have the exact sequence $0\to J\to R\to R/J\to0$ and tensoring with $I$ you get
$$
I\otimes_RJ\to I\otimes_RR\to I\otimes_R R/J\to 0
$$
so $I\otimes_R R/J\cong I/K$ and it's not difficult to show that $K=IJ$. Then check that the map $I\otimes_RR/J\to R/J$ translates to the map
$$
I/IJ\to R/J, \quad a+IJ\mapsto a+J
$$
whose kernel is $(I\cap J)/IJ$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And how can help this to prove that if $R=I+J$ then $I \cap J=IJ$ ?

Comment: @Jotabeta That would be a big detour for a very simple fact. Anyway, $R=I+J$ implies $R/I\otimes_RR/J=0$